# System hangs when copying a large binary files in python

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, wxpython

I have created a utility software for operating file copy  process in python.Every thing is working nice but when i start copying  any files larger than 2 Gb the the whole system hangs. It seems to me that it might be a memory leak issue.

I  have tried:

- Copying it using Shutil Module
- Using Lazy operation by copying Chunks of Bytes
- Copying Files data LINE by LINE
- Using Fileinput Module
- Adjusting Buffer million times
- Writing copy file part with C and then Extending it with python.

...but none of this has worked.

Here are links to my [File Script](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16634607/schizocopy.py) and my [GUI Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schizocopy/files/latest/download):

I'm using Windows 7 with 2 Gb of RAM.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is encouraged to psot a small amount of code that reproduces the exact problem you're having. Without this it is most unlikely that the community will be able to help answer your question. Please also note that posting links to code off-site is very much discouraged. You can edit your question to correct these things by clicking the "edit" link above.

Comment: @Maulwurfn Can you link please? OP's current profile does not show any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 2 GB of memory when you copy a file that's larger than your memory, it causes issues. Don't load the entire file into memory. Instead, I would do something like:

```
with open(myLargeFile) as f:
   with open(myOtherLargeFile, "w") as fo:
   for line in f:            
      fo.write(line)
```

Since this can potentially take a long time, you should put this into a separate thread from your GUI or the GUI will appear to hang. Here are a couple links on that topic for wxPython:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Answer (score 0):

The good approach for this problem is:

- use multiprocessing or multithreading
- split file into chunks
- use python dbm for storing which chunk belongs to which filename, filepath and chunk offset( for file.seek function)
- create queue for read and write chunks

Comment: Most of this is poor advice. `multiprocessing` (or threading) will not make the copy faster (in fact, it may will likely slow things down), and `dbm` is utterly unnecessary. Simply reading and writing fixed-size chunks is all that is necessary.

Comment: @duskwuff den i don't understand why my system hangs when i copy file above 2 gb ...i m using fixed sized chunks with  buffers in my script...But unfortunately nothing working..